# How to obtain Asympotic Relation for coefficent

Tags: complex-analysis

> $(1-z)^{-m}=\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_nz^n$
>   
> Then Obatin following asympotic relation for coefficent 
>   $$a_n\sim \frac{1}{m-1!}n^{m-1}  , n\to \infty$$

$(1-z)^{-m}=1+mz+\frac{m(m-1)z^2}{2}+......=\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_nz^n$
Differentiating n times I get,
$a_n=\frac{m!}{(m-n)!}$

Which is not equal to required Where is my mistake?
Any Help will be apprecited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your calculation of the derivative isn't right - try it again.  You should end up with 
$$ \frac{d^n f}{dz^n}(0) = \frac{(m+n-1)!}{(m-1)!}. $$
Second, the coefficient $a_n$ is not the $n$th derivative at zero, it is the $n$th derivative at zero divided by $n!$: so
$$ a_n = \frac{(n+m-1)!}{n!(m-1)!}.$$
You could write this as
$$a_n= (n+m-1)(n+m-2)\cdots (n+2)(n+1) \frac{1}{(m-1)!}.$$
Compare this to what the coefficients are supposed to be asymptotic to, and remember that $a_n \sim g(n)$ means $a_n/g(n) \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$ and that $m$ is fixed.  See if you can take it from there.